# validate the credit card in authorize.net without specifying the amount

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

According to the api we can authorize the credit card. But in that process we have to put the amount and other information. What if i only want to validate a credit card not to charge it.

Actually i only want to verify whether the user is putting the correct credit card or not. because the system have to go through the hands of laymen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't validate a credit card is legitimate without processing a transaction. You can validate the format  of the card number is valid and the card is not expired, but not if it is real or active.

To validate a credit card is valid without charging it you need to do an AUTH_ONLY for either $0.00 or $0.01 depending on your processor's requirements. If it is approved, and the amount is $0.01, you should then void that transaction.

Comment: is it ok to pay thr `$0` ? i mean to validate only can i use the no payment way?.  i have to also void the transaction ?

Comment: If you do they AUTH_ONLY for $0.00 there is no need to do a VOID as you have not frozen any funds on the user's credit card.

Comment: yes i am using `"transactionType": "authOnlyTransaction"`

Comment: i have a question in this also that this is validating the credit card but what about the ACH? i mean there is no help available to validate the account

Comment: To validate an ACH account you need to use a third party service like [Plaid](https://plaid.com/products/auth/) who will make micro deposits for you and then require the user to verify the amounts deposited. But a service like that is not free.

Comment: auth.net did not provide the functionality to check the ACH?

Comment: ACH works very differently than credit cards. There is no way to verify it like you can with credit cards. That's why you need a specialized service like Plaid.

Comment: but what if i pay a small amount like i did in the case of credit card it validate the ACH also ?

Comment: The ACH transaction is not in real time so you will only be told if the transaction worked on Authorize.Net's end. It doesn't mean the funds are available.

Comment: sorry did not understand what you mean by realtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170682/discussion-between-tech-geek-and-john-conde).